# Count total number of occurrences using grep

Tags: grep

`grep -c` is useful for finding how many times a string occurs in a file, but it only counts each occurence once per line. How to count multiple occurences per line?

I'm looking for something more elegant than:

```
perl -e '$_ = <>; print scalar ( () = m/needle/g ), "\n"'
```

Comment: I know `grep` is specified, but for anyone using `ack`, the answer is simply `ack -ch <pattern>`.

Comment: @KyleStrand For me ack -ch <pattern> only counted the lines with occurrences and not the number of occurences

Comment: @MarcKees Looking at the man page, that sounds like the correct behavior. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Similar: [Counting occurrences of \[a\] word in \[a\] text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398413/80216).

Comment: As @user4518 notes in a comment below, the `perl` code example given above erroneously  _"only counts the occurences in the first line."_

Answer (score 586, accepted):

grep's `-o` will only output the matches, ignoring lines; `wc` can count them:

```
grep -o 'needle' file | wc -l
```

This will also match 'needles' or 'multineedle'.

To match only single words use one of the following commands:

```
grep -ow 'needle' file | wc -l
grep -o '\bneedle\b' file | wc -l
grep -o '\<needle\>' file | wc -l
```

Comment: Note that this requires GNU grep (Linux, Cygwin, FreeBSD, OSX).

Comment: @wag What magic does `\b` and `\B` do here?

Comment: @Geek \b matches a word boundary, \B matches NOT a word boundary. The answer above would be more correct if it used \b at both ends.

Comment: For a count of occurrences per line, combine with grep -n option and uniq -c ... grep -no '\<needle\>' file | uniq -c

Comment: @jameswarren `uniq` only removes adjacent identical lines, you need to `sort` before feeding to `uniq` if you are not already sure that duplicates will always be immediately adjacent.

Comment: how to find the occurences for multiple words seperately?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on WSL, it report a smaller number of occurences on large files. `grep 'needle' file -c` works in my case

Comment: @tripleee For efficiency, use `sort -u` rather than `sort | uniq`. Here, `sort` is not necessary since matches from the same line in the source will be consecutive lines in the output.

Comment: @JivanPal This was in the context of `uniq -c`, which `sort` cannot do. Of course, if you know identical lines will always be adjacent, you don't need `sort` at all, which they will be if your pattern is just a static string, but not in the general case.

Answer (score 23):

If you have GNU grep (always on Linux and Cygwin, occasionally elsewhere), you can [count the output lines from `grep -o`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/grep-multiple-times-per-line/6985#6985): `grep -o needle | wc -l`.

With Perl, here are a few ways I find more elegant than yours (even after it's [fixed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/grep-multiple-times-per-line/6982#6982)).

```
perl -lne 'END {print $c} map ++$c, /needle/g'
perl -lne 'END {print $c} $c += s/needle//g'
perl -lne 'END {print $c} ++$c while /needle/g'
```

With only POSIX tools, one approach, if possible, is to split the input into lines with a single match before passing it to grep. For example, if you're looking for whole words, then first turn every non-word character into a newline.

```
# equivalent to grep -ow 'needle' | wc -l
tr -c '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' | grep -c '^needle$'
```

Otherwise, there's no standard command to do this particular bit of text processing, so you need to turn to sed (if you're a masochist) or awk.

```
awk '{while (match($0, /set/)) {++c; $0=substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)}}
     END {print c}'
sed -n -e 's/set/\n&\n/g' -e 's/^/\n/' -e 's/$/\n/' \
       -e 's/\n[^\n]*\n/\n/g' -e 's/^\n//' -e 's/\n$//' \
       -e '/./p' | wc -l
```

Here's a simpler solution using `sed` and `grep`, which works for strings or even by-the-book regular expressions but fails in a few corner cases with anchored patterns (e.g. it finds two occurrences of `^needle` or `\bneedle` in `needleneedle`).

```
sed 's/needle/\n&\n/g' | grep -cx 'needle'
```

Note that in the sed substitutions above, I used `\n` to mean a newline. This is standard in the pattern part, but in the replacement text, for portability, substitute backslash-newline for `\n`.

Answer (score 7):

If, like me, you actually wanted <s>"both; each exactly once",</s> (this is actually "either; twice") then it's simple:

```
grep -E "thing1|thing2" -c
```

and check for the output `2`.

The benefit of this approach (if exactly once *is* what you want) is that it scales easily.

Comment: I'm not sure you're actually checking it's only appearing once? All you're looking for there is that either one of those words exist at least once.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No need to use `wc -l`, `grep` has a built-in option to count things, and it is even named as obvious as `-c` for “count”!

Comment: @rugk You completely missed the first sentence in OP's post, which explicitly explains that `-c` only counts **one** occurrence per line. If a string occurs 1000 times on the same line, `grep -c` will still only count it as one. This answer makes no sense at all for this question.

Comment: The whole point of the question is exactly that the `-c` option does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution using awk and `needle` as field separator:

```
awk -F'^needle | needle | needle$' '{c+=NF-1}END{print c}'
```

If you want to match `needle` followed by punctuation, change the field separator accordingly i.e.

```
awk -F'^needle[ ,.?]|[ ,.?]needle[ ,.?]|[ ,.?]needle$' '{c+=NF-1}END{print c}'
```

Or use the class: `[^[:alnum:]]` to encompass all non alpha characters.

Comment: Note that this requires an awk that supports regexp field separators (such as GNU awk).

Answer (score 3):

I had a need to do this but for more than one search term. And I wanted them to be listed in columns with the number of occurrences of each.

My bash-only, one-liner, solution is as follows:

```
grep -o -E 'borp|flarb' flarb.log  | sort | uniq -c
 910 borp
9090 flarb
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example only prints out the number of occurrences per-line, and not the total in the file.  If that's what you want, something like this might work:

```
perl -nle '$c+=scalar(()=m/needle/g);END{print $c}'
```

Comment: You are right -- my example only counts the occurences in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

This is my pure bash solution

```
#!/bin/bash

B=$(for i in $(cat /tmp/a | sort -u); do
echo "$(grep $i /tmp/a | wc -l) $i"
done)

echo "$B" | sort --reverse
```

Comment: This is rather inefficient and brittle. [Don't read lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and the broken quoting  will cause this to fail where the input file contains lines with whitespace of shell metacharacters.