# Verify that /etc/passwd has correct number of fields on each line?

Tags: text-processing, users

I'm looking for an easy, portable way to validate the number of fields in /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow, /etc/group and /etc/master.passwd. This would run on FreeBSD, Linux and other Un*xes. [pwck](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_pwck.htm) does this, and more, but it only runs on Linux-based systems.

How can I count the number of fields separated by colons in /etc/passwd?

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
```

Following the example in "[grep: count total number of occurrences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/grep-count-total-number-of-occurrences)", I came up with the following quick hack:

```
cat /etc/passwd | while read LINE; do echo $LINE | grep -o ':'  |wc -l; done
```

But I'm looking for a better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`awk -F: ' NF!=7 {print}' /etc/passwd`

should do it.  If the number of fields is not 7, then print it out.