# Awk or Sed: If pattern is found: delete line && export variable

Tags: bash, awk, sed, python, gnu

In my bashscript I want Sed to find `debug: Debug` in a file `${SourceP}` and if found delete that line and export to the environment `Debug=Debug`

```
sed -i '/debug: Debug/,+0 d' ${SourceP} && export Debug=Debug
```

But unfortunately, the `Debug=Debug` is getting exported even if the pattern is not found.

How can I achieve this: export `Debug=Debug` only if the pattern is found and delete the line.

Is it not possible to achieve with Sed?

---

I tried this with `awk` but this also doesn't work:

```
awk -i inplace '!/debug: Debug/' ${SourceP} && export Debug=Debug
```

---

Edit: I hope to search for `debug: Debug` exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export information out of the `awk` part somehow. Either you can export a variable, or use an [exit status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16566/awk-forcing-a-return-status).

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN {err = 1}; {if (NR == 1 && /([[:space:]]|^)debug: Debug([[:space:]]|$)/) {err = 0} else {print}}; END {exit err}' ${SourceP} && export Debug=Debug
```

### Explanation

- `BEGIN {err = 1}`: initially, set the error status to 1.
- Then if you are on the first line `NR == 1` and `&&` there is `/([[:space:]]|^)debug: Debug([[:space:]]|$)/` on that line, set the error status to 0 (`err = 0`). Else, print all other lines. This regex is `debug: Debug` starting with either whitespace or at the start of the line, and ending with either whitespace or the end of the line.
- When the `awk` script ends, exit with the error status `{exit err}`.
- Hence, if `/debug: Debug/` was found in the file, the error status would be 0 and the `&&` would run.

Comment: Thank you! Also, how to limit awk to search `debug: Debug` only at the line number = 1 of the file?

For example, If line 1 contains `abcd debug: Debug xyz` I expect it to work?

Comment: Your solution also accepts `debug: DebugError`? How can we search exactly for `debug: Debug`?

Comment: No worries. I basically followed your regex in the question. What exactly is the phrase you want? `abcd debug: Debug xyz` is okay, but `debug: DebugError` is not. So you want either whitespace or nothing adjacent to `debug: Debug`?

Comment: Yes I hope whitespace or nothing adjacent to it

Comment: Okay, updated. The command is getting a bit massive with the edits, but hopefully you can still understand it!

Answer (score 1):

```
test "$(sed -i -e '/debug: Debug/{w /dev/fd/1' -e 'd}' "$SourceP")" && export Debug=Debug
```

Notes:

Writing `${SourceP}` is pure mannerism; it's just as dangerous as the simple `$SourceP`. You want to *quote* it instead: `"$SourceP"` or `"${SourceP}"`.

`/dev/fd/1` is supported on most modern Unixes; `sed -i` and `awk -i` are GNU specific and highly unportable.