# counting occurrences of a string

Tags: grep, sort

I have a large database of this format:

```
0500506 gi|561108321|ref|NC_018143.2|   71446   0 
0500506 gi|561108321|ref|NC_018143.2|   71447   0
0500508 gi|561108321|ref|NC_018143.2|   71449   0
0500509 gi|561108321|ref|NC_018143.2|   71447   0
```

What I want to do is to create a new table with the number of occurrences of each of the third column, something like this

```
71446 1 0500506
71447 2 0500506,0500509
71449 1 0500508
```

Importantly, the whole lines won't match, so I want to make sure that I'm just matching the values in a single column. I'm assuming I can adapt one of the solutions from 
[Count total number of occurrences using grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/grep-count-total-number-of-occurrences), but am not sure how.

Thanks very much,
drea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` might be more up to the task

```
awk '{sep=$3 in a?",":"";b[$3]++;
     a[$3]=a[$3]sep$1}; END{for (k in a) print k, b[k], a[k]}' file
```