# Count the number of matches in less

Tags: less

In `less`, is there a way or trick to quickly count the number of matches instead of pressing N repeatedly and counting the matches manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct method, but you can hack your way around. The following command will pipe everything from the first line on the screen to the end of the file to `grep -c ... | less`, opening a new instance of `less` to show the output of `grep`, which will be the number of lines matching the pattern:

```
g|$ grep -c <pattern> | less
```

When you quit this `less`, you'll be back to the first `less`.

Other tricks:

- <strike>`&pattern` and then pipe to `wc -l` using `g|$` like above, to use `less`'s pattern matching</strike>
- jump a number of matches (e.g., do `10n` x times until it fails, then proceed by y single steps to get 10x+y matches).

Comment: After `&pattern`, piping still pipes the non-filtered content (with `g|$wc -l`, that will give you the number of lines between the first occurrence of `pattern` and the end of the input)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas oh, that's disappointing.

Answer (score 7):

If `less` is displaying a file, issue

```
!grep -c pattern %
```

"A percent sign (%) in the command is replaced by the name of the current file", as `man less` tells us.

Unfortunately, since `less` is displaying stdin when used with `man`, you cannot do the same when reading manual pages. Refer to [muru's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607463) in that case.

Comment: Thanks, the % bit is the one I need :) BTW, when displaying stdin input, aside from piping to another less like in @muru's answer, we can also save it first to a temporary file: `s /tmp/foo` then examine the file: `:e /tmp/foo`, then perform your trick above. Quite a few keystrokes, but problem still solved.

Comment: Since I can only choose one answer, I chose muru's. But upvoted your answer as well, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not fixed to *less*, you could type:

```
grep MYSEARCHEXPRESSION MYFILE | wc -l
```

Or:

```
grep MYSEARCHEXPRESSION MYFILE| less -N
```

Then the last line has the amount of matching lines in line number.

look also:

- [Count total number of occurrences using grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/count-total-number-of-occurrences-using-grep)

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with grep. Specifically asking for establishing this inside less' interactive interface. For a comparison, in emacs I can do M-x count-matches. Tricks are allowed. For example, &PAT is close.