# Counting matches with grep, when multiple matches per line are possible

Tags: text-processing, grep

The standard usage of `grep` is to return lines that match a pattern.

If a line can contain several matches of the pattern, how can I count each match individually, not the [total number of matches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/count-total-number-of-occurrences-using-grep)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count total number of occurrences using grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/count-total-number-of-occurrences-using-grep)

Comment: Also similar: [Counting occurrences of \[a\] word in \[a\] text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398413/80216).

Comment: Note that despite OP's confusing edits, this question is asking the same thing: "what will isolate each match on a line of its own" is exactly what is done in "grep's -o will only output the matches" and is what's in the accepted answer as well.

Comment: And now OP has edited the question yet again to asking something else altogether. Please don't drastically change questions that have been answered multiple times.

Comment: Please don't change your question after receiving answers. You can clarify, but not completely change so that the answers are no longer relevant. I have rolled back your edits to the last version that seems to match the answers you have been given. If you have more questions, please ask them separately, as new questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `grep` command has a `-c` option that counts *the number of lines* matched by a pattern. Since the standard usage of `grep` is to return lines that match a pattern, this solves the task "count the number of matches".

If a line can contain several matches of the pattern, you may use `grep` with its non-standard `-o` option if you want to count each match individually.  This isolates each match on a line of its own.
You may then count the number of matches by passing the result through `wc -l`.  This uses `wc` to do the actual counting, not `grep`.  However, you could cheat and use `grep -c .` in place of `wc -l` to count the number of non-empty lines returned from the first `grep`.  Since that is a bit of a hack, and since `wc -l` does literally what we want, we'll use `wc` in the examples below.

See the manuals for `grep` and `wc` on your system.

Example: The number of lines matching the pattern `G` in `file`:

```bash
$ grep -c -e G file
7
```

Example: The number of matches in the same file, but counting each match individually:

```bash
$ grep -o -e G file | wc -l
      18
```

Comment: Beware `grep -o` only prints the non-empty matches. For instance `seq 10 | grep -c '^'` prints 10 but `seq 10 | grep -o '^' | wc -l` prints 0.

Comment: There's also the usual question of whether overlapping matches should be counted (like if there are one or two occurrences of 99 in 999 or of aba in ababa).

Comment: A perhaps less trivial example: ``seq 10 | grep -c '7*'`` prints 10, but `seq 10 | grep -o '7*' | wc -l` prints 1.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{a += gsub(/pat/,"&"); } END{print a}' file
```

Or

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i ~ /pat/)  ++a}END{print a}'
```

The command is slightly changed for overlapping matching taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13210/469418).

```
$ echo abababa | awk '{ while (a=index($0,"aba"))  {++count; $0=substr($0,a+1)}}END{print count}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`, you could do:

```
perl -lsne '$count++ while m{$regex}g; END{print +$count}' -- -regex='perl regex'
```

That has the advantage of also counting empty matches such as:

```
$ seq 10 perl -lsne '$count++ while m{$regex}g; END{print +$count}' -- -regex='\b'
20
```

(20 word boundaries in the contents of the lines of the output of `seq 10`).

With `perl` regexps, you can also handle some cases of overlapping matches by using look-around operators:

```
$ echo abababa | perl -lsne '$count++ while m{$regex}g; END{print +$count}' -- -regex='aba'
2
```

```
$ echo abababa | perl -lsne '$count++ while m{$regex}g; END{print +$count}' -- -regex='(?=aba)'
3
```

Which instead of matching on occurrences of `aba`, matches on the positions within the line where `aba` can be seen ahead.